# What are the server requirements for Silverlight 2?

Tags: .net, apache, iis-6, silverlight-2.0

Can a Silverlight 2 enabled web page be managed from an Apache server? (I'm not actually interested in doing this but trying to understand Silverlight 2 a bit more.)

Assuming that I have IIS6 and Server 2003 what are the .NET version requirements to host a web site with Silverlight 2? Are .NET 3.0 and 3.5 required on the server? My thinking is not because this is a client side technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Silverlight is a browser technology, it is **server-agnostic** and can be hosted on a variety of server platforms: LAMP, UNIX, and IIS. You don't have to install .NET or any other Microsoft software on the server.

The only configuration required on the web server is to **register the MIME types for content being served**. If not already registered, you'll have to add following entries.

There are three MIME types required:

- .xaml - application/xaml+xml
- .xap - application/x-silverlight-app
- .xbap -  application/x-ms-xbap

Here are some instructions [how to do that for Apache and IIS](http://blogs.technet.com/jorke/archive/2007/09/11/silverlight-mime-types-in-iis6.aspx).

Needless to say, some features such as [WMS Streaming](http://blogs.msdn.com/jitghosh/archive/2007/11/30/demo-live-streams-in-silverlight.aspx) rely on a server supporting them.

Comment: You mean the server doesn't need to know a thing about .Net? I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from mime types there should not be a dependency on a particular server technology.

With newer IIS versions, mime types have been locked down more so you need to add an entry for a .rar file (example). It may be the case that a server admin might customize the mime configuration and prevent a .xap file from being downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The [system requirements for Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/overview/faq.aspx#sys-req) and associated technologies are listed below.

```
* Windows
      o Operating System: Windows Vista; Windows XP Service Pack 2
      o Intel® Pentium® III 450MHz or faster processor (or equivalent)
      o 128MB of RAM
* Mac OS
      o Operating System: Apple Mac OS X 10.4.8 or above
      o Intel Core™ Duo 1.83GHz or faster processor
      o 128MB of RAM
* Linux. For the system requirements, please refer to the Mono Project's Moonlight Web site.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server can serve the XAP files, there should be know problem hosting Silverlight in any server you want.  Silverlight is a client technology.  Your server just sends it to the browser and it's up to the client to do anything with it.